# python why isnt my varibles changing and useing my dictionary

Tags: python

so im doing a class assignment and i have to make this basically but when i run my program it doesnt pull the numbers from my dictionary adding them. when i put hot brew into the input item it doesnt add 4.25 to num1 or any of the others

```
import time

coffee = {"hot brew": 4.25,
 "latte": 4.75,
 "mocha": 4.99,
 "cold brew": 3.95,
 "cappuccino": 4.89,
 "dount": 1.50}
num8 = 0
while num8 == 0:


    num7=0
    while num7 == 0:
        items = input("what items would you like to buy or leave blank to end your order")

        num1=0
        num2=0
        num3=0
        num4=0
        num5=0
        num6=0


        total=0

        if items == "hot brew":
            num1 = num1 + coffee["hot brew"]
        elif items == "latte":
            num2 = num2 + coffee["latte"]
        elif items == "mocha":
            num3 = num3 + coffee["mocha"]
        elif items == "cold brew":
            num4 = num4 + coffee["cold brew"]
        elif items == "cappuccino":
            num5 = num5 + coffee["cappuccino"]
        elif items == "dount":
            num6 = num6 + coffee["dount"]
        elif items == "":
            num7 = num7 + 1
        else:
            print("that item does not exit")
    total = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6
    total = total * 1.07
    print ("your order is " + str(total) + "$")
    time.sleep(5)
    leave = input("would you like to close the program yes or no")
    if leave == "yes":
        num8 = 1
```

Comment: put the `num1 = 0` and etc. _outside_ the while loop. As-is, every time the loop runs they get reset to zero.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your title. Instead, [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment of num1 through num8 is happening within the loop, so it gets reassigned to zero after the loop runs through. Take these variables and define them outside the loops, maybe just after the coffee dictionary, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `num1-num6` variables are `initialized` within the loop. So each time the loop increments, those variables are getting `reassigned to zero`. You will have to define it outside the `num7 == 0` loop.